# Local extrema of function of 2 variables

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima

$$f(x,y) = x^4 + x^2 - y^4 - y^2$$

I've tried to find the partial derivatives and I get $2(2x^3+x)$ for $x\;$ and $\;-2(2y^3+y)\;$ for $y.$

Then I solved the equations $\;2(2x^3+x)=0\;$  when $\;x=0\;$ and $\;-2(2y^3+y)=0\;$ when $\;y=0.$
 So extremum is $\;(0,0).$

Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: It is a critical point. Infact, it is not an extremim because $f(x,0)=x^2+x^2\ge0=f(0,0)\ge -y^4-y^2=f(0,y)$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron a typo in the first one, but right conclusion.